# Geoserver: huge CPU load when delivering tiles at higher zoom levels

Tags: geoserver, maximum-coverage-problem

We are working with geoserver for the first time. We have it running on a quite powerful server, 32GB and 12 kernels.

For the raster we want to deliver we have already seeded all cache tiles for all zoom levels, i.e. from 0 to 19, which is the max zoom.

When looking at the CPU load while accessing the tiles there is no unusual behavior of the CPU load (around 10% to 30%).

However, when one gets to zoom level 19 the CPU load jumps to 300+%, reaching even >1000% (corresponding to the utilization of almost all available kernels).

How can this be? There is no tile generation, since they are already all available, so the cpu should not be used in this manner. Their delivery should not be different from other zoom levels, as far as I understand it, so there should not be more CPU activity than with lower zoom levels.

Is this a bug?

Does someone know the reason and maybe also the solution to this problem?

I prepared a video to show what a mean, please look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0VbULDyj7c

Comment: How did you configure the raster? What service are you hitting the layer with (WMS, TMS, WMTS)? Is it the requested projection / format the same projection as you configured for the layer?

Comment: We are delivering the raster by WMS. Yes, the layers and the requested projection are identical (shouldn't this last point be irrelevant once you have seeded all tiles in the same projection as you will deliver them, even if the original layer is in another projection - which in our case is not)
What do you exactly mean with the first question?

Screenshots of our configurations:

Comment: _sorry, did not know that editing comment is limited to 5 min_
Screenshots of our configurations:
WMS: http://screenpresso.com/=WEife
Raster access: http://screenpresso.com/=P9c0b
Caching defaults: http://screenpresso.com/=Cr2Z

What would you wish to look at more?

Comment: What version of GeoServer is that?

Comment: We are running version 2.9.0

Comment: I see that you didn't get an answer. I'm having the same problem. Did you ever resolve it?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/100955)